# all stuffs of my sd card showing under others file in sd card

Tags: sd-card

[image]i am currently using 730 lumia. yesterday i  downgraded my  os from 10149 to 8.1 due to excess storage taking in phone memory and  after  reset my phone, i was  moved all the files from  sd card to my pc. after formatting my sd card(class 10 transend 16gb)  i put  my all stuff again in sd card..but when i saw my storage in mobile , my all stuffs are showing under the others file.  but if i mange to music from music under storage sd card then it  is managing but in the music file under storage shoing 0 bytes and same thing happening with all types of folder...but all stuffs are in same location where it was. please help me...i am trying  6-8 time in different ways to put all the file in particular folder but same things are repeated every time. here is my attachment.

please hep me...and when i insert my sd card into the ohone showing  and another option..m s

Comment: Did you copy/paste the folder structure IN ADDITION to the files?